# Spring batch read remote csv file by chunks and process them by chunks

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, sftp

I have a requirement to read a CSV file (consisting of 40k+ records) by chunks from a remote linux box location and then pass the chunk info to the processer and writer without downloading the file locally, I want to get an idea or references for how to achieve this requirement.

I have gone through the below approaches but am not really sure whether these approaches read the file in chunks or not, I also see there is ***"sftpremotefiletemplate"*** can someone please suggest whether I am in the correct direction or do I need to use sftpremotefiletemplate (or any other approach)?

```
@Bean
public Job readRemoteCsvFileJob(Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("readRemoteCsvFileJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .flow(step1)
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(ItemReader<MyItem> reader, ItemWriter<MyItem> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<MyItem, MyItem>chunk(10)
            .reader(reader)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<MyItem> reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader<MyItem> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new UrlResource("/remote-path/myfile.csv"));
    reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<MyItem>() {{
        setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
            setNames(new String[]{"field1", "field2"});
        }});
        setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyItem>() {{
            setTargetType(MyItem.class);
        }});
    }});
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> can someone please suggest whether I am in the correct direction

Yes, using `URLResource` with the `FlatFileItemReader` is the way to go. The reader will stream data from the remote location in chunks, it will not download the file locally.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but as I have mentioned I will be having the file on the remote server and how to I need to establish an Sftp connection and integrate it with the reader?

Comment: opening/closing the SFTP session could be done in the `open/close` methods. Those methods are designed for resource initialization/cleanup.

Comment: Thanks for clarification but my question is how come reader knows that it reads from particular remote host (urlResource we are only mentioning the file path) where exactly we need to linkup sftp host details, authentication details with the reader, not sure if I am missing something. It would be really helpful if you can provide some references

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an example with SFTP. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud for your time and for providing valuable info, I will explore more into it.